# Applying function to a specific subkey for each key using a dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to carry out a dictionary comprehension that applies a function to a specific inner subkey only. The function removes non-English words from strings. I would like it to be applied to the `'title'` subkey *only*, for each key in the dictionary.

```
# imports

import nltk

# function to remove non-English words

words = set(nltk.corpus.brown.words())

def strip_non_en(string, words):
    " ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(string)\
    if w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())
    return string


# dict example:

meta_data = {
'12345.xml': {'author': ['Presley'],
'date': 1956,
'doi': None,
'title': 'Heartbreak Hotel'},
'67890.xml': {'author': ['Iglesias'],
'date': 1972,
'doi': None,
'title': 'For a little bit of your love Por Un Poco De Tu Amor'}
}
```

I can only get it to apply the function to all sub-keys, which tends to remove the contents of the `'author'` sub-keys.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to structure your logic. Similar to Ajax1234 but I add an extra optional parameter to `strip_non_en`.

```
word_set = set(nltk.corpus.brown.words())

def strip_non_en(string, words=word_set, key=None):
    if key in (None, 'title'):
        string = ' '.join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(string) \
                          if w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())
    return string    

new_dict = {a: strip_non_en(b, key=a) for a, b in meta_data.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the current key is `'title'`, and if so, call the function and pass the current value to the function:

```
new_dict = {a:strip_non_en(b, words) if a == 'title' else b for a, b in meta_data.items()}
```

Also, you can slightly change your function `strip_non_en` so that the parameter `words` is optional. That way, `words` does not have to be passed everytime:

```
def strip_non_en(string, words=words):
  " ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(string)\
  if w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())
  return string

new_dict = {a:strip_non_en(b) if a == 'title' else b for a, b in meta_data.items()}
```